# How sort by two values as desc in one sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have advertisements table. In there i have two dates. You can put adv and add option to show top on the list. I created top_list_end_date and i can order by that date is simple. is another date up_date if your adv is on second page or on bottom you can up date and looks like fresh adv should be on top of the list.

```
SELECT id, up_date, top_list_end_date 
FROM advertisements
ORDER BY top_list_end_date desc, up_date desc;
```

But doesnt work. [image]
I would like adv id 202 as first in results cause up_date is higher. How can i do this in one sql ?

UPDATED answer
Thank You for help everyone. Thanks to you i found the answer:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 1 as own, id, up_date , top_list_end_date FROM advertisements WHERE top_list_end_date > now()
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 as own, id, up_date, top_list_end_date FROM advertisements  WHERE top_list_end_date IS NULL

) a
order by own, up_date desc
```

result is

[image]

i have two groups. First with top_list_end_date 
second without that date. Both groups should be sort by up_date only
but i wanna show first group no 1 (top_list_end_date) and below group 2 all the rest.

as u can see 197 is first cause top_list_end_date exist and up_date is highest. and the same in second group id 213 up date is highest.

:) thx again

Comment: I don't understand the question. Maybe see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: (Although I assume you just want COALESCE in conjunction with the answer already provided).

Comment: Seems like i need first get all data sort by top_list_date and from that collection  sort data by up_date

Comment: @Wraith seems like is not enough. You should provide your expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT id, up_date, top_list_end_date 
FROM advertisements
ORDER BY COALESCE(top_list_end_date, up_date) desc;
```

If the top list date is `NULL`, then the up date is used.

Note:  You might also want the largest value.  If so:

```
SELECT id, up_date, top_list_end_date 
FROM advertisements
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN top_list_end_date < up_date OR top_list_end_date IS NULL
               THEN up_date
               ELSE top_list_end_date
          END) desc;
```